# See if Django form submission came from the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm new to django, so I apologize if this has been asked. I'm using the `post_save` signal to run a task when a new object is created. I need to be able to check if the form was submitted from the admin page or if it was submitted on the live website, is this possible? Where might I find documentation on this?

Comment: `post_save` is an ORM signal. It has no idea about the web framework (i.e. forms, users, etc). You must use a view or a middleware to check that information.

Answer (score 0):

**`post_save` is too late in the process to log or take action on the source of the object.**

`post_save` is a signal sent from the database/ORM, i.e. it is what is called after a save is done. Does the save function take any input about the source? No. Does that function put anything into the ORM or the database about the source? No.

You want to take whatever action it is in the `view` function where this occurs. Here is the simplest way to do it that I can think of. I shall assume that your preferred choice of action is to save where it was created in the database.

Consider the following:

```
class YourObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creation_location = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Admin")
```

Here we have an object with a `name` and a `creation_location`, the purpose of the second being to tell where the object is created. To prevent any need to edit the `Admin` functionality, as that can be a pain, the default value is set to `Admin`.

Onto the view:

```
def create_model_view(request):
    your_object = YourObject.objects.create(name='FirstObject', creation_location="View")
```

Here we have a view with a create function for the object. In the initialization, the default value of Admin for the `creation_location` is overwritten and set to View.